# Deploy nodejs app in another server through Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, deployment, pm2

I want to deploy a Node.js app on another server, I have set it up Jenkins in one server and but I need to deploy the Node.js app on another server by using the pm2 service.

I'm able to login into the server from the Jenkins with the command **ssh root@servername** (**servername** is the server which I want to deploy), and I have configured the git access and when I run the build command in Jenkins it is cloning the code in Jenkins server itself, but I want to connect to the server and then clone the code and install dependencies and start the Node.js app from pm2 in another server.

Comment: What command are you using to clone the repo? To run this remotely you can use the SSH command from the Jenkins server.

Comment: I'm cloning the code from git plugin in Jenkins and yeah in build section I have given **ssh root@servername **  here what's happening is when I trigger the buildnow command in Jenkins, its cloning the code in Jenkins server and after that Jenkins executing the Build commands where I have given the ssh command to log in to the another server . here it's logging into another server but since the code is cloned into the Jenkins server, it was not able to deploy the code

Comment: You can do `ssh root@servername git clone repo-url` to pull the code remotely.

Comment: Ok I will try that

Comment: I assume that you have SSH PPK access set up already, so when that command is issued on the Jenkins box, it does not need a password entered into stdin.

Comment: I have added other node as Jenkins Slave and resolved the issue